# CMake Error: Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files: QUICKFIX_LIBRARY linked by target "run" in directory

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, cygwin, clion

I try to build a project on CLion with Cygwin and I got this error :

```
-- Found Boost: /usr/include (found version "1.66.0") found components: system thread regex iostreams chrono date_time atomic 
-- Configuring done
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
QUICKFIX_LIBRARY
    linked by target "run_engine" in directory /cygdrive/c/Users/33671/Desktop/main_program

-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```

I try to generate the .exe fail but nothing appeared because of this error.
Any idea ?

Comment: It looks like some of your CMake files need the Quickfix library to be installed, but CMake can't find it.

Comment: @rturrado yes thank you, i found the issue. I had to change the path of QUICKFIX_LIBRARY because it was defound with NOtFOUND. So i had to add it in CMakeCache.txt

Comment: Great! In order to make your CMake files more portable, you may be interested in having a look at `FetchContent_{Declare, _MakeAvailable}`. It's a way of letting CMake download and install a package to your build directory. You'd still need to do things like `target_include_directories(myapp ${quickfix_SOURCE_DIR}/include)` and `target_link_libraries(myapp quickfix::quickfix)`. But you shouldn't worry anymore about manually installing a package, or setting paths to local folders. Downside to this is that not every project out there is suited to be used with `FetchContent`.

Answer (score 0):

So I changed the Path of QUICKFIX_LIBRARY in the CmakeCache.txt and then I don't have the error. But in reality it's still not finding it because once it's written in CMakeCache.txt, it doesn't check anymore if it's really include or not.

My lib is located like this : project_name/exchanges/quickfix/lib/cygquickfix-16.dll.

The lib is cygquickfix-16.dll.

I added a control message to see if he found or not the library.

I still have an ERROR at the end.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
SET(Boost_USE_MULTITHREAD ON)
SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH /lib/)

FIND_PACKAGE(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system thread regex iostreams)#  1.66.0

IF(Boost_FOUND)
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    LINK_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
ENDIF(Boost_FOUND)

SET(USED_LIBS ${Boost_SYSTEM_LIBRARY} ${Boost_THREAD_LIBRARY} ${Boost_REGEX_LIBRARY} ${Boost_IOSTREAMS_LIBRARY})

add_executable(run_engine main_poco.cpp ....)

include_directories(.)
include_directories(./exchanges/quickfix/include)

find_library(QUICKFIX_LIBRARY quickfix HINTS ./exchanges/quickfix/lib)
message("-- QUICKFIX_LIBRARY: ${QUICKFIX_LIBRARY}")

target_link_libraries(run_engine ${QUICKFIX_LIBRARY} -lPocoDataMySql -l...)
```

And then I get this in CMake Debug :

```
C:\Users\33671\AppData\Local\JetBrains\CLion2022.1\cygwin_cmake\bin\cmake.exe -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/make.exe -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/c++.exe -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" -S /cygdrive/c/Users/33671/Desktop/project -B /cygdrive/c/Users/33671/Desktop/project/cmake-build-debug
-- QUICKFIX_LIBRARY: QUICKFIX_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- Configuring done
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.

Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
QUICKFIX_LIBRARY
    linked by target "run_engine" in directory /cygdrive/c/Users/33671/Desktop/project

-- Generating done
CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.
```